# Run Time Error 9 and rowDateTimeArray bug

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a data log formatter module on excel. I was told that this code works but everytime I run the program I get a run time error 9 message. I have attached the code that is highlighted when I try to debug the program.

```
        'Split date and time
        rowDateTimeArray = Split(rowDateTime, " ")
        rowDate = rowDateTimeArray(0)
        rowTime = rowDateTimeArray(1)
```

The last `rowTime = rowDateTimeArray(1)` is what is being highlighted when I try to debug.

Comment: Does ```rowdatetime``` have a space in it? You will get an error if there is only 1 element in the array.

Comment: `Debug.Print UBOUND(rowDateTimeArray)` will tell you how many elements you have. You are assigning 2 variables which means you will need at least two elements in your array. Sounds like this is your error as noted by @Warcupine

Comment: 'Write column headers in "Formatted Log" sheet
    Dim colNumArray(0 To 17) As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer
    Worksheets("Formatted Log").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
    Worksheets("Formatted Log").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Time"
    colNum = 3